# Finding minimum $ x $ value that minimizes a function.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, maxima-minima, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-analysis

First let provide an example:

Let's have
$$ f(x)=\sin(x)$$
[image]

$ x $ values that make this function are shown in the picture as $A=4.712$, $B=11$, $C=17.28$, $\dots$

I want to find the minimum $x$ value that minimizes $ f(x)=\sin(x)$ which is point $A$ with $x$ value of $x=4.712$.

how can I write it mathematically?

One idea is using $\operatorname{argmin}$ function $\operatorname{argmin} f(x)$.

another Idea is using bilevel optimization which finds the minimum value of  $f(x)$.

Something like this:

$Z= \min \operatorname{argmin} \big(y=f(x)\big)$

but I don't know how to write it in a way that mathematically be reasonable and acceptable for publishing. I want to specifically define exactly indices and sets $t$ for $x$, $f(x)$ and $Z$ and the indices in lower part of $\operatorname{argmin}$ and other functions if required.

Comment: $x$ is simply 3π/2.

Comment: do any of the tags apply?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for an appropriate notation, then since $\textrm{arg min}_x f(x)$ is the *set* of $x$ values that minimise $f$, you could write $\min(\textrm{arg min}_x f(x))$ to represent the minimal element of that set.

Just remember that depending on the definition $f$ and its domain, this element might not exist - for example, for $f(x) = \sin x$ when the domain of $f$ is all real numbers, then $\textrm{arg min}_x f(x) = \{(2k - \frac{1}{2})\pi : k \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{\ldots, -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3 \pi}{2}, \ldots\}$ which has values going to infinity in both directions. Or $f(x) = 1 - H(x)$ where $H$ is the Heaviside step function has $\textrm{arg min}_x f(x) = \{x > 0\}$ whose infimum does not lie in the set, and it has no minimum element.

Comment: Thank you. So in case, I want to add a subscript for $min$ in $min(arg minxf(x))$ what should I add. in fact if I want to write it more accurate, I may write 
$$f(x)=sin(x)$$
$$h(???)= argmin(f(x))$$
$$G(??? , ???) = min(arg minf(x))$$  

or I may use $$ f(x)=sin(x) \ \ \ \  \vee  x >0 $$     
$$ h(???) \ \ \ \  \vee  ??? >0 $$ $$ G(???) \ \ \ \  \vee  ??? >0 $$

Comment: As a general rule, if you define your notation before you use it and it's clear to readers then you can write things however you like. If you want to restrict the domain of the function, you could either (a) include it in the subscript of the argmin - e.g. $\textrm{arg min}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^+}$ or (b) use set operations to change what set the min is operating on, e.g. $\min((\textrm{arg min}_x f(x)) \cup \mathbb{R}^+)$